# Convert Web Form to Razor Syntax

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, webforms

I have the following snippet as web form. Need to convert it to Razor, but cannot find the corresponding html helpers. This snippet contains a FileUpload and Button to upload and save the MP3 files to database and an ASP.Net GridView control to display the uploaded files and also allows the user to play and download the MP3 Audio file.

```
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload"
   onclick="btnUpload_Click" />
<hr />
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" RowStyle-BackColor="#A1DCF2" Font-Names = "Arial" Font-Size = "10pt"
   HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White">
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="FileName" />
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data='dewplayer-vol.swf?mp3=File.ashx?Id=<%# Eval("Id") %>'
   width="240" height="20" id="dewplayer">
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
<param name="movie" value='dewplayer-vol.swf?mp3=File.ashx?Id=<%# Eval("Id") %>'/>
object>
ItemTemplate>
asp:TemplateField>
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="Id" Text = "Download" DataNavigateUrlFormatString = "~/File.ashx?Id={0}" HeaderText="Download" />
Columns>
asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Got it, I will refrain next time.

Answer (score 1):

There are many scenarios where you cannot. See this stackoverflow response: [Convert webform control to Razor syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10794139/540537).

If I were you, I'd run the Webform as is (not converted), then view the source of what is rendered which should be html/css/javascript, finally copy that source into your razor page and begin adding your iterators, conditions, and other logic to reproduce the dynamic portions.

You might also try searching for a converter like the [one](https://github.com/telerik/razor-converter) Telerik built.